# Return value depending on similar record exists

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working lists of members in a team. The team can have 1 leader or 2 co-leaders.

Table: **Position**

```
Position_ID | Position_Name
```

Table: **Involvement**

```
Position_ID | Project_ID | Person_ID
```

In the **Position** table, Position_ID '7' has the Position_Name 'Leader / Co-leader'.

Suppose there is John (Person_ID = 5) who takes part in project with Project_ID = 2 and in that project he has Position_ID = 7.

- If there is Jim (Person_ID = 9) who also takes part in that project (Project_ID = 2) and also serves at that position (Position_ID = 7), the position for John with Person_ID = 5 is 'Co-Leader'. Return array(person_id => 5 , name => John, position => Co-leader, position_id => 7, project_id => 2)
- If there is not, the position for John is 'Leader'. Return array(person_id => 5 , name => John, position => Leader, position_id => 7, project_id => 2)

My reasoning so far:

- Select from Involvement, join Member to get member details and join Position to get position name.
- If the position ID is not 7, which means it's not the leader / co-leader case, then let it be.
- If the position ID is 7, check in Involvement if there exists a record with the same position ID and project ID but different person ID.
- If there is, cut the latter half out of the Position #7 name and return 'co-leader' only. If there isn't, cut the former half and return 'leader' only.

Problem: I don't know how to express "the person id of another record is different from the person id of the current record".

Simplified MySQL

```sql
SELECT 
    IF(`i`.position_id = 7, 
        IF(EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `i` WHERE ????),
           SUBSTRING...,
           SUBSTRING...)
        ,po.`name`) 
    AS `position`, 
    FROM `involvements` i 
    JOIN `members` m ON m.`id` = i.`person_id`
    JOIN `positions` po ON po.`id` = i.`position_id`
    WHERE i.`project_id` = 2
```

Comment: Sorry, how do you decide which one is co-leader again?

Comment: If there are 2 rows in the Involvement table that have the same Project_ID and same Position_ID but different Person_ID.

Comment: I guess I need to visualize the desired results as I can see multiple ways to return co-leader records, but I'm not sure what you expect in the data set.  Could you provide a sample of expected results?  For left join to involvements and members after positions again to return an additional column if a co-leader exists. Join based on position where the person ID is not already defined on the record. But I don't know if you want an added column or something different...

Comment: Return array(person_id => 5 , name => John, position => Co-leader, position_id => 7, project_id => 2) or array(person_id => 5 , name => John, position => Leader, position_id => 7, project_id => 2)

Comment: Yes, but HOW do you decide that John is the co-leader, and not the other person.

Comment: @Strawberry if there are 2 persons with position id 7 in a project, then **both of them** will be co-leaders.

Comment: If there is only John then John's position is leader. If there are Jim and John then both of them are co-leaders.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will get you moving in the right direction..  But as I don't understand your view of desired data layout... it may not be exactly what you're after.

The join simply identifies if there are two people on the same project with the same position 7.  If any records are found, then those records are co-leaders which is identified in the case statement.

```
SELECT i.person_Id
   , m.name as MemberName
   , case when i2.po.position_ID is null then po.name 
          else 'Co-Leader' end as Position
FROM `involvements` i 
JOIN `members` m 
  ON m.`id` = i.`person_id`
JOIN `positions` po 
  ON po.`id` = i.`position_id`
LEFT JOIN involvements i2 
  on i2.`position_Id` = po.`position_ID`
 and po.position_ID = 7
LEFT JOIN members m2 
  on m2.`id` = i2.`personID`
 and m2.`person_ID` <> m.`person_ID`
WHERE i.`project_id` = 2
```

Comment: I would like to receive this kind of result: array(person_id => 5 , name => John, position => Co-leader, position_id => 7, project_id => 2) or array(person_id => 5 , name => John, position => Leader, position_id => 7, project_id => 2), depending on whether there is Jim or not.

Comment: Updated... Added for position specific join for 7 (leader/coleader) and added case to convert name to co-Leader and limit fields to desired fields.

Comment: Why do you join the members table twice? The i2 involvements table contains the person_id already, if that's not the same as in the i alias, then it's not the same person. And with this modification you arrive to the solution I provided.

Answer (score 0):

Left join the positions table once more where the project id and position id are the same, but take only those records that have a position id of 7 (leader) and the person id does not match. If there is no such record (values from that table will be null), then it's a leader, otherwise it's a co-leader.

```
SELECT 
    IF(i2.person_id is null,'leader','co-leader') 
    AS `position`, 
    FROM `involvements` i 
    INNER JOIN `members` m ON m.`id` = i.`person_id`
    INNER JOIN `positions` po ON po.`id` = i.`position_id`
    LEFT JOIN `involvements` i2 on i.project_id=i2.project_id and i.position_id=i2.position_id and i.person_id<>i2.person_id and i2.position_id=7
    WHERE i.`project_id` = 2
```

Comment: I need to apply this method to the Head / Co-head case and President / Co-president case in other types of team so I should replace the 'leader', 'co-leader' with SUBSTRING?

Comment: Yes, you have to. Additionally, you need to provide those position ids in the left join's join criteria, in case the position ids are different. I would use the in() operator.